# how/what to feel about sth

Tags: word-choice

Someone breaks some bad news to you. You are taken aback, and you say "I don't know **how** to feel about this".

My question is, should it be "I don't know **how** to feel about this (one)",or should it be "I don't know **what** to feel about this (one)"?

Answer (score 2):

Both are correct.
They *could* have different nuances of meaning... but, for the most part, both sentences are the same.

Here are some *possible* different nuances to the word choices;

1. I don't know **how** to feel about this. This construction *could*
   refer to an emotional response to what was stated; I don't know
   whether to be happy, sad, excited, bummed out, etc. about this.
2. I don't know **what** to feel about this. This construction *could* refer to a degree of belief in what was stated; I don't believe this, I can not believe this, I don't want to believe this, etc.
3. It is also possible that **what** to feel about this can refer to a
   *future possible action* from the person saying this sentence.  In other words; I am wondering if I should punish, cheer on, reprimand
   or praise, etc. whatever **"this"** is.

In normal spoken conversations, either sentence could be said with equal intent and both would be correct.

Answer (score 0):

A common, idiomatic response in this situation is:

> I don't know what to say.

This phrase can be used any time we feel at a loss for words. It is often used as an empathetic response to shocking or sorrowful news. In fact, there is even a book entitled *[I Don't Know What to Say: How to Be a Blessing to Cancer Patients and Others in Crisis](https://www.indiebound.org/book/9781540339966)*.

---

As for your wording, instead of saying:

> I don't know how **to feel** about this.

I think it would sound more natural if you said:

> I don't know how **I feel** about this.